# Sorting Through HTML Elements with multi worded input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to show elements based on an input's value, and would like it so that people can type in multiple words, and sort through the elements to show only the elements that apply to their search.

JS Bin, extremely basic example: https://jsbin.com/zabikejuxa/edit?html,js,output

Such as having a full list of vehicles, and if a customer types in '2015', only the 2015 vehicles would display. If the customer types in '2015 Buick', it would loop through, and only display 2015 Buicks, not displaying elements on the based that had '2015' or 'Buick'.

The first word of the query is working just fine, it's when the value is greater than 2 words that everything gets complicated.

Comment: [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: @Draco18s If an item in my list is 3 words long, and someone happens to skip word #2, such as having a "Year Make Model", and a customer only types in "Year Model", that particular search (and most other functions) don't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Working modifications [here](https://jsbin.com/toxopoxequ/edit?html,js,console,output)

There were a couple of issues:

- `if($('#searchText').val() > 2)` caused the search to be parsed as a number and compared with 2, what you want is `$('#searchText').val().length`
- the loops conceptually were inside-out: you want to find whether each row contains all terms, so the `for` loop should be inside the `$.each`.
- unless you need case-sensitive matching, call `toLowerCase()` on the text and the search terms